# Como compilar mi codigo JavaFX a un .jar o a un .exe

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Hola tengo un proyecto acabado de `JavaFX` con `Maven` y no encuentro la manera de compilar el codigo a un .jar, trabajo con `IntelliJIDead` y cuando le digo al `Maven` que compile el programa, me deja un .jar en la carpeta target que no se ejecuta, ¿alguien conoce la manera correcta de hacerlo? o si me falta algo para el funcionamiento correcto?

Answer (score 0):

1. Entra a **Project Structure...** (`Ctrl + Alt + S`)
2. En el panel izquierdo seleccioná **Artifacts** que está dentro de **Project Settings**.
3. En el panel intermedio, arriba a la derecha el simbolo más `+` y seleccionar **JAR** (suele ser el primero de la lista) y seleccionas la opcion **From modules with dependencies...**
4. En el campo **Module** seleccioná tu proyecto y en **Main Class** buscá y selecciona la clase que tenga el main de la aplicación.
5. El *radio button* tiene que estar seleccionado en **extract to the target JAR** y le das al botón de `OK`. Seguido a esto `Apply` y `OK`
6. Vas al menu desplegable `Build` y seleccionas **Build Artifacts**. Ahí te aparece un cuadrito y seleccionas **Build** y el .jar se te va a crear en la carpeta *out/artifacts* de tu proyecto

Para ejecutar el .jar te recomiendo leas y sigas [estos pasos](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres necesitas dos cosas: descargar todas las dependencias (jars) de tu proyecto y modificar el manifiesto del JAR de tu proyecto para agregar estas dependencias al *CLASSPATH* y para definir la clase "main".

**1 - Descargar dependencias del proyecto (JARs)**

Para hacerlo puedes usar el plugin de Maven ***maven-dependency-plugin***. Agrega la siguiente definición en el POM en la sección *build > plugins*.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/libs
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Esto copiará las dependencias en el directorio *target/libs*.

**2 - Crear JAR ejecutable (modificar el MANIFEST.MF)**

Para esto usamos el plugin de Maven ***maven-jar-plugin*** de la siguiente forma (esta configuración la agregamos al POM igual que se indica en el paso 1):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                <!-- Aquí debes poner el fully qualified class name de la clase "main" -->
                <mainClass>paquete.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Una vez hecho esto el JAR de tu proyecto estará listo para ejecutarse con el comando `java -jar mi-jar.jar` (IMPORTANTE! la carpeta *libs* debe encontrarse enel mismo directorio que el JAR).

Ten en cuenta que al tratarse de una aplicación JavaFX requerirás agregar al *modulepath* aquellos módulos de JavaFX que uses en tu aplicación (revisa [este enlace](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) que es el mismo que te compartió @andres en su respuesta).

No obstante hay una *hack* que te puede ser de utilidad si tu aplicación no es modular y quieres evitarte el tener que agregar los módulos de JavaFX al *modulepath*. Consiste en crear una clase "main" que no herede de `javafx.application.Application` (esta sería adicional a la que si hereda de dicha clase) y desde el método *main()* de esta llamar al método *main()* de la que sí herada de `javafx.application.Application`. Luego debes definirla como "main class" en el POM. En mi repositorio [Cross-Platform JavaFX App skeleton](https://github.com/betanzos/cross-platform-app-fx) podrás encontrar un ejemplo de esto último.